# Jersey rest server - Return different structure for list as json

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, tomcat

I'm experiencing a different json structure of a returned list when running on Tomcat.

```
{
    "apartment": [
        {
            "apartmentName": "ABC",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "apartmentName": "DEF",
            "id": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since the controller is returning List of apartments; ideally it should start with square braces [] instead of curly braces. This results into JSON parser on client side think that it's a JSONObject instead of JSONArray. I am not sure how to fix this. Below are the various POM dependency and their version.

Tomcat version I am using is 7.0.67

jersey-server-1.19
jersey-servlet-1.19
jersey-json-1.19
jersey-spring-1.19
jersey-core-1.19

Comment: What I am expecting the response to be                                                      [                                                                                                                           {
    "apartmentName": "ABC",
    "id": "1"
},   { "apartmentName": "DEF", "id": "2"}  ]

Comment: Problem got resolved after using JACKSON instead of JAXB

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're returning a List of Apartments from your servlet. You can fix this by returning an array like this

```
return new Apartment[]; // Collect all apartment objects and return it as an array
```

and Jackson will convert it accordingly. In your case I think you have  Java object that has a parameter called `apartments` of type `List`. I assume you're using Jackson as the provider.